# ls-command: how to display the file size in megabytes?

Tags: command-line, unix, ls, mega

In Unix (Tru64), how do I make the `ls` command show the file size in megabytes? Currently I am able to show it in bytes using the following:

```
ls -la
```

Answer (score 272):

Maybe `-h` is sufficient for you:

> -h
>   When used with the -l option, use unit suffixes: Byte, Kilobyte,
>               Megabyte, Gigabyte, Terabyte and Petabyte in order to reduce the
>               number of digits to three or less using base 2 for sizes.

```
ls -lah
```

General advice: Use `man commandname` to read the manual/help of a certain command, e.g. here `man ls`.

Comment: Thanks, but -h option does not seem to exist on Tru64 Unix.

Comment: General advice: install GNU utilities ...

Comment: +1 for the man pages(+5 if I could!). They are a priceless resource when you don't know how to do something with a particular command.

Comment: I like your tip about using man, but really, searching on Google is so much faster than using man a lot of the time (as now, when I found this result on Google).

Comment: Google's fine and all for general hints, but ultimately man pages are system/OS, even host specific, usually created when the software is compiled or installed, and thus, authoritative for the software on your particular system.

Comment: Just to come full circle, there's man online for gnu/linux: http://linux.die.net/man/

Comment: Can we set MBs as default?

Comment: `ls --help` usually has enough information vs `man ls`

Comment: Mnemonic: `h` stands for human-readable

Answer (score 34):

`ls --block-size=M` prints the sizes in Megabytes but shows 1MB also for anything below 1 MB. I'm unsure if this option is acceptable in your UNIX version of ls, though.

Actually `ls -lh` also prints sizes in Gigabytes if the file is big enough (Well anyways: on **Linux** 64bit this does work :>)

On a side node: `du -sh *` prints also directory sizes in current directory.

Comment: Thanks! I needed to monitor live file changes in a folder and using `ls -h` is meaningless after a file grows over 1GB, so I use this command in a 1 second loop: `while true ; do  ls -al --block-size=M ; sleep 1 ; done`

Answer (score 17):

You will have to use `awk` to do the math for you:

```
ls -l | awk 'BEGIN{mega=1048576} $5 >= mega {$5 = $5/mega "MB"} {print}'
```

This won't affect the output for files that are smaller than `mega`.

You may need to adjust the field number to match the way your `ls` is laid out. You can change `mega` to "1000000" if that is your preference.

This will print more decimal places than you probably want. You could implement a rounding function.

Comment: Much less elegant than `ls -lh` or `ls --block-size=M`, but AWK is very useful!

Comment: Just what I needed. All the other solutions round to the nearest MB but this shows a few decimal places and is easily customizable.

Comment: This is a nice solution for those systems (AIX - I am looking at you) that do not have the -h option.

Answer (score 13):

try `ls -shR` for recursive human readable format.

Comment: [OP has stated that there is no `-h` on Tru64](http://superuser.com/questions/190653/ls-command-how-to-print-file-size-in-megabytes#comment193423_190654), and did so over two years before this answer was posted.

Comment: Thought It's my responsibility to help those who reach here with the same google search.

Answer (score 9):

try `ls -lash`, it prints sizes in human readable format

Comment: I kept forgetting this, but now I won't. "human memorizable format" :)

Answer (score 5):

`du -sm filename.txt`

Comment: it always round up the size...if size is less than 1 MB say 500K, then also it will print 1M

Answer (score 5):

You can also type

```
du -sh ./*
```

This will list all the folders under current directory, with human-readable format, including the more familiar file sizes in Kb, Mb, Gb.

Comment: In [that reply](https://superuser.com/a/633214) was posted a `du` implementation, that can show sizes in human readable format with 3 decimals:

`du -Lsbc * | awk 'function hr(bytes) {hum[1024**4]="TiB";hum[1024**3]="GiB";hum[1024**2]="MiB";hum[1024]="kiB";for (x = 1024**4; x >= 1024; x /= 1024) {if (bytes >= x) {return sprintf("%8.3f %s", bytes/x, hum[x]);}}return sprintf("%4d B", bytes);}{print hr($1) "\t" $2}'`

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the size of only a specific file, then the command, a trivial extrapolation of the previous answers, is:

```
ls -sh filename(s)
```

`-s` is for size and the `h` is for Human Readable (as mentioned above a few times).

The output will look like this:

```
753M myfilename
```

If you leave out the filename(s), it'll list the directory, placing the size of each file next to its name — not unlike what `ls -la` does when invoked with no filename arguments.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This question is about Tru64 Unix, and the OP stated almost five years ago that the `-h` option does not exist in `ls` on that system.

Answer (score 2):

```
ls -l --block-size=MB
```

For the `--block-size` parameter:

- use `MB` for 10^6
- use just `M` for 2^20

Comment: Note that this **won't show any decimal places**. Also, **anything above 0 kB but nor greater than 1 MB will be shown as `1MB`**. For this reason I found `ls -l --block-size=kB` to be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just interested in the file size, and you don't have to use the `ls` command, try the following:

```
# echo "Hello World" > file.txt
# ls -l file.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 12 Mar 10 11:32 file.txt
# stat --printf='%s\n' file.txt
12
```

This will print the file size without the need to parse anything.

Comment: OP want size in MB, maybe a stat option will produce size in human readable form ?

Comment: Ah, that was dumb of me.  Thanks for catching that.  stat does not have an option to manipulate the size using --printf or any other option as far as I know.

It would likely require using a combination of printf and bc command-line utilities.  In which case, why bother.  ls and cut/awk would be quicker.