# "du -h" with more decimal places

Tags: linux, bash, format, du

I'm working on a little util tool written in bash that gives me some information about a game server on Linux. For that reason I need a possibility to display the size of the file contents.

I'm doing that right now by using this:

```
du -Lshc *
```

It works almost perfect! The only flaw is that it displays stuff like this:

```
21G     backups
22G     server
8.0K    start.sh
151M    world.zip
43G     total
```

This is fine but I want more digits. Meaning it should look like that:

```
21.587G     backups
22.124G     server
8.089K      start.sh
151.198M    world.zip
43.436G     total
```

Is there a possiblility to do that?

I wouldn't mind using a complex command since I use it in a `.sh` file so I won't type it by hand every time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
du -Lsbc * | awk '
    function hr(bytes) {
        hum[1024**4]="TiB";
        hum[1024**3]="GiB";
        hum[1024**2]="MiB";
        hum[1024]="kiB";
        for (x = 1024**4; x >= 1024; x /= 1024) {
            if (bytes >= x) {
                return sprintf("%8.3f %s", bytes/x, hum[x]);
            }
        }
        return sprintf("%4d     B", bytes);
    }

    {
        print hr($1) "\t" $2
    }
'
```

awk-function based on [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/gawk-awk-tcsh-how-to-convert-large-number-to-human-readable-mb-gb-etc-597921/#post2951685).

One could probably make the output look a bit nicer by piping it through `column` or left-padding it with spaces.

**Edit:** Added the left-padding.

Also, to sort the list: `du -Lsbc * | sort -n | awk` and then the awk-script.

Comment: This is almost perfect. It only has a little issue if the file size is 0. Then no number is displayed. Another thing is that there are decimal places if the unit is B (Meaning it looks like `108.000B`. Which is some kind of akward.) But thank you anyways!

Comment: To use for `ls -l` as well, `if ($5>0){ $5 = hr($5) }` and same for `$1`, then just `print` to print the re-assembled `$0` with one or the other field modified.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my bash implementation using the code of @n.st

```
hr() {
    bytes=$1
    hum[1024**4]="TiB";
    hum[1024**3]="GiB";
    hum[1024**2]="MiB";
    hum[1024]="kiB";
    x=0
    for ((x = 1024**4; $x >= 1024; x = ($x/1024) ))
    do
        if [ "$bytes" -ge "$x" ]; then
            $(printf "%8.3f %s" $( echo "$bytes $x" | awk '{printf "%.2f \n", $1/$2}' ) ${hum[$x]});
            return 0;
        fi
    done
    echo $(printf "%4d     B" $bytes);
}
```

Try

```
echo $(hr 1024);
echo $(hr 4096);
echo $(hr $((1024*500)) );
echo $(hr $((1024*8000)) );
echo $(hr $((1024*1024*500)) );
echo $(hr $((1024*1024*1024*500)) );
echo $(hr 2127780017);
```

Output

```
1.000 kiB
4.000 kiB
500.000 kiB
7.810 MiB
500.000 MiB
500.000 GiB
1.980 GiB
```

Comment: The question was about making `du` output in that format. Not creating a function/script that takes the size as a parameter. You couldn’t even pipe `du` into it.

Comment: @BrainStone Yes, who knows maybe someone will need my implementation some day.

Comment: `awk` is about as portable as `bash`

Comment: I tried to put this into a `bash` script so I could call it at the command-line and supply a directory to it. I tried modifying the code so that it would take in a directory instead, but I was not successful in doing so. It would be extremely helpful if you actually modified this so that it could take in a directory, which would then find the size of the directory then call your function. As is, this function doesn't directly answer the question and I find it not useful.